# how to change color of a page in rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple rails app with users and post modal, what i want to do is to add a simple button on the show page of each post, which when a user click will change the color of the whole page to a dull greyish color from the usual white one. It will be much like a reading mode for the user.
Each user can go to reading mode only for themselves not for other users who visits the same post.

I tried searching the internet but found nothing more the *how to change button colors.*

Comment: It'd be helpful if you add to your question what you've tried.

Comment: Changing page color is not very different from changing button color. In fact, it's exactly the same. Just pass another selector to jquery call

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rails. JavaScript is responsible for handling button clicks and interacting with the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing a class in the DOM with something like jQuery

```js
var $body = $('body');
var $toggleStylesButton = $('.toggle-styles-button');
    
$toggleStylesButton.on('click', function() {
  $body.toggleClass('reading-mode-on');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

body.reading-mode-on {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Body content</p>

<button class='toggle-styles-button'>Toggle styles</button>
```

But if you intend it to be a setting that persists - that would be a rails specific thing - that may add a class to the body based on the user's preferences.